# Saving Prefav Data In Unity between scene transition

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a game where the data to be displayed in the Main Menu is fetched from the API. I store the data in a class and loop through the data to map the data in the Menu.

```
        foreach(var dt in mainMenuDto.data)
    {
        GameObject _catogeryPrefabTemp =  Instantiate(catogeryPrefab);
        Vector3 originalSize = _catogeryPrefabTemp.transform.localPosition;
        _tabGroup.objectsToSwap.Add(_catogeryPrefabTemp);

        _catogeryPrefabTemp.transform.SetParent(catogeryParent.transform);
        _catogeryPrefabTemp.transform.localPosition = originalSize;
        _catogeryPrefabTemp.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
        foreach (var item in dt.games)
        {
            Texture2D image = await (GetRemoteTexture(item.thumbnail));
            tex.Add(image);
            await _catogeryPrefabTemp.GetComponent<CatogeryInitialise>().InstantiateGame(gameButtonPrefab, item.slug,image);
        }

    }
```

Now , this works fine but when I change the scene and come back to The main Menu, the whole mapping process takes place again. How do I change the main menu to be saved even during scene changes.

Answer (score 0):

Use [DontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html)

This method will tell unity to keep your menu between scenes. You will be able to see it under separate DontDestroyOnLoad label in your scene hierarchy.

Comment: I am saving the json data using DontDestroyOnLoad, I need to save scene data now. I cannot use it on the particular menu gameobject as DontDestroyOnLoad dosent work on children. And saving the entire canvas is going to make two scenes load at the same time.

Comment: Ok, it's a bit more clear to me now, but how do you want to preserve your data without keeping it or mapping again? I may be wrong, but afaik there isn't a way to save prefabs during runtime. You could maybe serialize your main menu and deserialize it on menu load, but how different is that to mapping? How about you detach your menu from canvas before exiting scene, use DontDestroyOnLoad on it and attach it to canvas later, would that work for you?

Comment: I tried that, and it works. Thank you so much.